# hadoop request specific machines from yarn

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I want to know whether I can request specific nodes from yarn resource manager when running a MapReduce?
In more detail, let say that there is a yarn cluster deployed with the following nodes nodeA, nodeB, nodeC.

Can I submit a MR job that will run only on nodeB and nodeC?

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no property till current versions of CDH and yarn which allow you to dynamically choose the nodes on which you want to run your jobs. This is taken care by the Resource Manager only.